# Moving object when button clicked- PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I’ve been trying to make an object move between three locations upon clicking a button. This is the code that I have now

```
def objectMove():
  If window.button.pressed():
    window.object1.setGeometry(200,120,91,91)
    window.object1.setGeometry(1,120,91,91)
    window.object1.setGeometry(90,120,91,91)
window.button.clicked.connect(objectMove)
```

My intention for this code was to have an object move to these three locations every time the button is clicked and the button can only be clicked 9 times before the screen times out. But I’m unsure how I could fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hold qrects of positions in dict under self_def_init_**

```
self.val = 0
self.val_dict = {0:QRect(200,120,91,91),1:QRect(200,120,91,91),2:QRect(200,120,91,91)}
```

**and update your method as below code**

```
def objectMove():
    windowObject.setGeometry(self.val_dict[self.val])
    self.val += 1

    if self.val == 3:
        self.val = 0
```